# Getresourceasstream returning null on Jboss 5

Tags: java, jboss, null

I am doing some tests to migrate my application from Jboss 4 to Jboss 5, my problem is the "getresourceasstream" is returning null on Jboss 5, even though it works on Jboss 4. Here's the code:

```
InputStream inputStream = RelatorioAction.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("path to jasper report");
```

So, does anybody know what's the difference between this working on Jboss 4 and not working on Jboss 5?

Answer (score 0):

I would try with the TCCL instead

```
InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path report);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Franck, but I keep getting NullPointerException.

Comment: Is it possible to see the expression you use in "path to jasper report" as well as the location of the report resource and the RelatorioAction.class in the war/ear archive?

Answer (score -1):

Try to keep your properties file in the 'src' package. In this way, it will always be in the classpath.